# How to get Ramda opposite?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

How can I can I get opposite value with ramda? I am trying to archive the following:

```
R.opposite(true) //false
R.opposite(false) // true
```

Comment: https://ramdajs.com/docs/#not ?

Comment: Thank you :) Their docs are really long and if you don't know the exact phrase it can be hard to find stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Felix mentioned, you can use [not](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#not) to negate a value:

> A function that returns the ! of its argument. It will return true when passed false-y value, and false when passed a truth-y one.

```
not(true) //=> false
```

An in case you need to negate the outcome of a function, you can use [complement](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#complement):

> Takes a function f and returns a function g such that if called with the same arguments when f returns a "truthy" value, g returns false and when f returns a "falsy" value g returns true.

```
complement(equals(true))(true) //=> false
```